# Knockout jQuery Validate binding Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use a binding handler with Knockout and jQuery Validate, but when I submit the form, the page reloads, does not validate and does not call the method on my view model.

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing please?

Here is my binding

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.validateEmailForm = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {      
            $(element).validate({
                errorLabelContainer: $("#updateEmailFormAlert"),
                wrapper: 'li',
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,                        
                        email: true
                    },
                    emailConfirm: {                                                
                        email: true,
                        equalTo: "#email",                    
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "Email is required",
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                    },
                    emailConfirm: {
                        required: "Confirm Email is required",
                        email: "Please enter a valid confirm email address",
                        equalTo: "Confirm Email must match Email"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function() {
                    viewModel.updateUserEmail();
                }
            });
        }    
    };
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Knockout; what is `update:` supposed to be?  If it helps you, keep in mind that `.validate()` is the _initialization_ method of the plugin and gets called _once_ on DOM ready event.   At that point Validation is automatically triggered by various mouse events.

Comment: Update is used to apply jquery plugins or add on to an element, after Knockout has done it's binding. This binding allows me to add a simple attribute to my form data-bind="validateEmailForm: {}", which will automatically run the code in update, once binding has finished.

Answer (score 0):

OK so all I had to do was to create an variable when creating my ViewModel instance, so that I could reference the functions inside of my ViewModel.

```
var userViewModel = new UsersViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(userViewModel);
```

Then in my submitHandler

```
  // activate the jQuery Validate on the form
     ko.bindingHandlers.validateEmailForm = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, bindingContext) {      
            $(element).validate({
                errorLabelContainer: $("#updateEmailFormAlert"),
                wrapper: 'li',
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,                        
                        email: true
                    },
                    emailConfirm: {                                                
                        email: true,  
                        equalTo: "#email",                    
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "Email is required",
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                    },
                    emailConfirm: {
                        required: "Confirm Email is required",
                        email: "Please enter a valid confirm email address",
                        equalTo: "Confirm Email must match Email"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function() {
                    userViewModel.updateUserEmail(data);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }    
    };
```